# How to insert a cell with value on every Nth row in a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

There is a list of different values as a continuos list (array) in a column.
We need them grouped and separated every Nth row (7th) in another column by inserting some text between them. **Not a whole row. Just a cell**. As a result they will be *"pushed-down"* the column.

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
|      |   Col2    |  Col3     |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | Sunday    | Group 01  |
|    2 | Monday    | Sunday    |
|    3 | Tuesday   | Monday    |
|    4 | Wednesday | Tuesday   |
|    5 | Thursday  | Wednesday |
|    6 | Friday    | Thursday  |
|    7 | Saturday  | Friday    |
|    8 | 10        | Saturday  |
|    9 | 20        | Group 02  |
|   10 | 30        | 10        |
|   11 | 40        | 20        |
|   12 | 50        | 30        |
|   13 | 60        | 40        |
|   14 | 70        | 50        |
|   15 | MERCURY   | 60        |
|   16 | MARS      | 70        |
|   17 | JUPITER   | Group 03  |
|   18 | VENUS     | MERCURY   |
|   19 | SATURN    | MARS      |
|   20 | EARTH     | JUPITER   |
|   21 | NEPTUNE   | VENUS     |
|   22 | Mary      | SATURN    |
|   23 | John      | EARTH     |
|   24 | Paul      | NEPTUNE   |
|   25 | Ann       | Group 04  |
|   26 | ...       | Mary      |
|   27 | ...       | John      |
|   28 |           | Paul      |
|   29 |           | Ann       |
|   30 |           |           |
|   31 |           |           |
|   32 |           |           |
|   33 |           |           |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I have so far tried and succeeded on having the desired result by using a simple query:

```
=QUERY(({"***Group";B1:B7;"***Group";B8:B14;"***Group";B15:B21;"***Group";B22:B25;}),"SELECT *")
```

I wonder though. Is there a more *"elegant"* as well as **general way** using either **formula or script**.

Comment: You want to insert a cell with some text in column B after every 7 existing entries? Or you want to copy the values from column B to column C whereby between each 7 entries an additional cell is inserted?

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes. In this case 7 existing entries. But for an extending column for quite a few many entries. Also not only just 7 existing entries. Another time could be 5 or 9 or.... Please do notice the incremented value in the end of the text as well "Group **01**"

Comment: I am puzzled on how to  _"cut the clusters"_ and make them dynamic without having to write each one of them explicitly.

Comment: It is easy to write a script that will push your values from column B into an array, insert every 7 (or any other fix number) entries an additional entry and pass the whole result into column C. However, if your incremented value is not always the same within the same column - how is the script supposed to know where to apply which interval?

Comment: It is always the same. I meant for another time.

Answer (score 1):

### I suggest you the following solution based on Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var firstRow=1;
  var column=2;
  var destColumn=3;
  var increment=7;
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var values=sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, lastRow,1).getValues();
  var array=[];
  var k=1;
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  for(var i=0;i<lastRow;i++){
    if(i%increment==0){
      array.push("Group "+k);
      k++;
    }
     array.push(values[i][0]);
  }
  var outerArray = [];
  for(var j=0;j<array.length;j++){
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(array[j]);
    Logger.log(array[j]);
    Logger.log(tempArray);
    outerArray.push(tempArray);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, destColumn, array.length, 1).setValues(outerArray);
}
```

**Workflow:**

- Push the contents of the column of interest into an array
- Insert an additional entry with content every `increment`th time
- Transpose the array into the `[column][row]` syntax
- Insert the values into the destination column

**References:**

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/banding.html#getRange())
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Works "almost" perfectly. Just one problem. Although it should stop -in our case- at `Group 4` it adds at least an extra Group in the end plus a few rows. If we change the increment/step (eg 5) it adds more. A nice enhancement would be if it could be turned to a function like `=insertcell(1,2,7)` with corresponding variables`row`, `column`, `destination` so one should not have to go into the script editor but just write the function in a cell.

Comment: _"...function like =insertcell(1,2,7) with corresponding variables `row`, `column`, `destination` "_.  Come to think about it, the variable `destination` is pointless. It would be the address of the cell the function is in. It would be nice though to have an option -`1` or `0`- whether to have the first (at the very top of the column) Group1 appear or not. So it could be `=insertcell(2, 7, 0)`

Comment: If the script adds extra rows probably you have additional empty cells in your sheet after the last entry in the column of interest, instead of  `var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow();` you can define `var lastRow=sheet.getRange(firstRow, column).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();` In order not to open the script editor - you can run the script as a macro. Just go to Tools->Macro->Import and add the function to the Macro List. Otherwise, you can also rewrite the script as you proposed above. The references in my answer should help you to adapt the sample script to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert arrays every Nth row:

```js
/**
 * Inserts string every nth row
 *
 * @customfunction
 * @param {Object[][]} arr Input Column
 * @param {number} every Nth row to insert
 * @param {string} str String to insert
 */
function insertText(arr, every, str) {
  for (
    var i = 0, j = 0;
    i < arr.length - 1 && arr.splice(i++, 0, [str + ++j]);
    i += every
  );
  return arr;
}
const arr = [ //Input col A1:A25 looks like this 
  ['Sunday'],
  ['Monday'],
  ['Tuesday'],
  ['Wednesday'],
  ['Thursday'],
  ['Friday'],
  ['Saturday'],
  ['10'],
  ['20'],
  ['30'],
  ['40'],
  ['50'],
  ['60'],
  ['70'],
  ['MERCURY'],
  ['MARS'],
  ['JUPITER'],
  ['VENUS'],
  ['SATURN'],
  ['EARTH'],
  ['NEPTUNE'],
  ['Mary'],
  ['John'],
  ['Paul'],
  ['Ann'],
];
console.log(insertText(arr, 7, 'Group'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Doesn't it mean though that the specific values should be entered one by one? I am looking for a more general approac using variables. Any other suggestion?

Comment: As [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098173/how-to-insert-a-cell-with-value-on-every-nth-row-in-a-column-in-google-sheets#comment102597647_58100563), something that one would not have to even mess with the script but just type a function on the sheet (like `=insertcell(2, 7, 0)`).

Comment: @mari You should have at least made a attempt at creating your own custom function. If you had, you would realize that this is a custom function. `=INSERTTEXT(A2:A15,7,"Group")`

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. And the educative negative review. It gave me the chance to recollect the [infamous Milgram Experiment](https://www.simplypsychology.org/milgram.html).

Comment: @mari I'm not sure I get the relevance.

Comment: _"[...If the answer was incorrect, the teacher would administer a shock to the learner, with the voltage increasing in 15-volt increments for each wrong answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment)"_. Sorry, that's the best I can do for you.